# How can I toggle a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two links
click1
and
click2

I want to make this two links clickable only one at a time. It should work in such a way that when I click click1, click 2 should not be clickable and vice-versa.

Comment: what you tried so far??

Comment: Atleast provide us something?

Comment: I think you've forgotten to add your code...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery and css; when the user clicks `click1`, `click2` will be disabled and vice versa.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o017Lant/)**

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 if ($(this).hasClass("click1")) {
     $(".click2").addClass("disabled");
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("click2")) {
     $(".click1").addClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

```css
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .25;
}

button {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click1">click 1</button>
<button class="click2">click 2</button>
```